# *.user.props missing in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In VS2012 - VS2015 I have used

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props

to setup global include paths for my working environment.

I can't find *.user.props for VS2017, are this files moved to some other location or is there some new way to handle this?

Comment: It is still the same.  Use the "visual" of VS with View > Other Windows > Property Manager.  Expand, say, Debug | Win32 and select Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.  The Properties window shows the path of the file.

Comment: Thx, same file is used from MSBuild\v4.0, I have expecting new one and blamed this for .sln not building, but error was more subtle :)